# How to change icon on AJAX results search by id

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have multiple icons, I want to change my certain icon to another icon based on the ajax result. For example, when the **res = true**, my bookmark icon needs to change to fa fa-address-card icon. Now the code is when the **res = true**, both icon will change. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
<i id="bookmark" class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
<i id="database" class="fa fa-database"></i>


$('i').removeClass('fa-bookmark');
$('i').addClass('fa fa-address-card');
```

Comment: Simply using the right selector, in the case of an `ID` is like `#YourID`, so: `$('#bookmark').DoSomething`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second jquery line is causing the problem

in both jquery selectors you are selecting all `i` tags in your html,,

first one isn't causing any trouble because it HAS 'fa-bookmark' and others don't so it will remove bookmark icon class

but in the second one you are applying `fa-address-card` to all `i` elements and that's why other icons are getting changed

```
$('#bookmark').removeClass('fa-bookmark').addClass('fa-address-card');
```

this is a better approach and will solve your problem